# If && condition to update a column in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to execute a simple line of command using if && operators in R. However, I don't see any output, and there is no error as well. Wondering what's happening. Appreciate all inputs. Thanks.

```
lws_data[,"WSR"] <- 
  if(lws_data$Ref && lws_data$PS >=270)
{lws_data$WSR=1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply if else logic across an entire column of a data frame in R, then use the `ifelse()` function:

```r
lws_data$WSR <- ifelse(lws_data$Ref & lws_data$PS >= 270, 1, lws_data$WSR)
```

The base R `ifelse()` function is *vectorized*, meaning that it seamlessly works across columns in its one line form.

Comment: The `&&` seems to be incorrect - you may need `&`.  Please check the output of `mtcars$mpg > 21 && mtcars$cyl == 6`